# Need to get a value till precision of 15 digit after decimal in DB2 Query

Tags: sql, db2

One of DB2 table column value is appearing as **0.3901369869709015** and we need to compare this value against my expected value as **0.390136986970901**. I tried to get the value from DB2 by using Decimal/Dec method. With that the value is getting round off and appearing as 0.390136986970902. Could you please help me to correct the below query that i am using to extract data from my **DB2** table.

SELECT DECIMAL(UV_FIELDSCOREMAP,15,15) AS UV_FIELDSCOREMAP From cvsinst.uv_occ WHERE CASEID = '20170720'

Answer (score 2):

Use `TRUNCATE(UV_FIELDSCOREMAP, 15)` instead.